# Trigger callback after clicking N times

Tags: javascript, html, button, click, show

I'm new in Javascript and I can't find the answer for my question. Is it possible that my javascript shows a div after if you clicked on a button 5 times? If this is the case, how can I make this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: After clicking on what? Yes it's possible: create a click event handler for whatever it is you want the user to click on, and have it count the clicks.

Comment: @nnnnnn Clicking on a button. Do I need Jquery for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Without jQuery:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   var button = document.getElementById('click_me');
   var elem = document.getElementById('message');
   var count = 0;

   button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       count++;
  
       if(count == 5){
           elem.style.display = 'block';
       }
    }, false); 
});
```

```css
#message {
  background: #0f0;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="click_me">Click Me</button>
<div id="message">Hello World</div>
```

**With jQuery:**

```js
$(function() {
  var count = 0;
  
  $('#click_me').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    count++;
    
    if(count == 5) {
      $('#message').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#message {
  background: #0f0;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="click_me">Click Me</button>
<div id="message">Hello World</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var clicks = 0;

function myFunction() {
  clicks = clicks+1;
  if(clicks == 5){
    document.getElementById('target').style.display = 'block'; 
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<div style="display:none;" id="target">You clicked 5 times</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to put two onclick at one button? I also have another function on the same button.

Comment: Yes, Just separate them with a ';', onclick="function1(); function2();"

Answer (score 1):

Do you need like this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 n=1;
    $(".clickable").click(function(){
        if(n==5){
   alert("You clicked 5 times");
  }else{
  n++;
  }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="clickable">Click here 5 times</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of function composition a general click handler function can be crafted to mimic how a real "[dblclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event)" behaves, but with a custom N amount of clicks.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')

const onClick = (requiredClicks, timeLimit = 300) => cb => {
  let timer;
  let clicked = 0;
  
  return e => {
    // each time clicked, check if reached the goal
    if( ++clicked == requiredClicks ){
      cb(e)
      clicked = 0
    }
    
    clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(() => 
      clicked = 0 // reset the number of clicks after a traditional 300ms duration
    , timeLimit)
  }
}

// bind events to all buttons, by their index, which controls the number of clicks 
[...buttons].forEach(
  (button, idx) => button.addEventListener(    "click", onClick(idx + 1)(callback)    )
)

// call this callback after N clicks (depending on the button in the demo)
function callback(e){
  console.clear()
  console.log("clicked on button at index", e.target.name)
}
```

```html
<h2>Click fast:</h2>
<button name='1'>Click once</button>
<button name='2'>Click twice</button>
<button name='3'>Click 3 times</button>
<button name='4'>Click 4 times</button>
```